# Thread stopping

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is stopping a thread by acting the "break" command at some point a safe way to stop a thread?

Comment: break is for loops.  Threads exit when the thread proc exits, or Abort is called on the thread.  Abort will cause an exception to be thrown on your thread.

Comment: What do you mean by `break`? The C# keyword? the keyword exits a loop and isn't related to threads at all.

Comment: if i have a server client that waits in a while loop for data from a client and i break that loop, doesn't the thread stop ?

Comment: No, it runs whatever code comes after the loop.  If it finishes that code as well, and reaches the end of the thread's main function, then the thread will stop.

Comment: For additional information to stop a thread look to my question:
[Proper way to stop a threaded job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146186/proper-way-to-stop-a-threaded-job-forced)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean doing something like this?

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //do something
        if(condition)
            break;
    }
}

//somewhere else...
Thread t = new Thread(SomeMethod);
t.Start();
```

If so, then yes, it's a safe way to end the thread.

Answer (score 3):

A thread abort, which I think is what you meant, is not a proper technique to use - unless the thread is also separated by an appdomain barrier.

Comment: Richter's "CLR via C#," 3rd edition, details the strategy on pages 617-618.  The "sponsor" appdomain, I'll call it, then catches a ThreadAbortException and calls the ResetAbort method on the dead thread.

Comment: any good links to where i can find a safe way to kill threads?

Answer (score 3):

If you are referring to the [Break()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break.aspx) method in Parallel.For, it is *specifically designed* to request a safe abort of the looping iterations.

An example of this technique is [described here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721.aspx)