# Start and stop(forced) a threaded job 

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to know a proper way to start and stop a threaded job forced and unforced. Is this the proper way to stop a Thread?

```
    public class ProcessDataJob : IJob
    {
        private ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> _dataQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();
        private volatile bool _stop = false;
        private volatile bool _forceStop = false;
        private Thread _thread;
        private int _timeOut = 1000;

        public void Start()
        {
            _stop = false;
            _forceStop = false;

            _thread = new Thread(ProcessData);
            _thread.Start();
        }

        private void ProcessData()
        {
            while (!_stop || _dataQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                if(_forceStop) return;

                byte[] data;
                if(_dataQueue.TryDequeue(data))
                {
                   //Process data
                   //.....//
                }
            }
        }

        public void Stop(bool force)
        {
            _stop = true;
            _forceStop = force;
            _thread.Join(_timeOut); 
        }

        public void Enqueue(byte[] data)
        {
            _dataQueue.Enqueue(data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no *proper* way to forcibly kill a thread.

There are several ways to do it, but none of them are *proper*.

Forcibly killing a thread is what you should do only if you need to terminate the program, or unload the appdomain containing the thread, and don´t care about any data structures left dangling in a corrupted/bad/locked state, because they will be gone in a short while as well.

There´s plenty of advice on the internet about how bad/evil Thread.Abort is, so don´t do it.

Instead, write proper cooperative threading. The thread(s) should themselves check a flag (event, volatile bool field, etc.) and then voluntairly exit when nicely asked to do so.

That is the *proper* way.

Comment: +1 I completely agree with you, and the OP is doint that already :-) So, when is it even thinkable to use `Thread.Abort`? Maybe never?

Comment: If you need to unload the appdomain (think kill a running extension/addin) or to exit the program, and you know/don´t care that there is threads running not configured with the IsBackground property. Basically, you want to quickly get rid of the appdomain/application and don´t want to properly wait for all threads to exit on their own. Though, to be honest, even in that context I would probably still not use Thread.Abort. Consider it like an operating system function, it is basically too low level for us mere mortals to handle. Let Eric Lippert and the guys take care of it.

Comment: Yes, for that I'd use `AppDomain.Unload` (which under the covers uses `Thread.Abort`).

Answer (score 1):

This is the way that I've done it in the past, with one difference. I've had threads unexpectedly hang in the past, which means that that loop of yours doesn't come back with an answer. To address this I have all thread using classes, like yours, register with a 'manager' class who is responsible for participating in key things like Forced Stop. The threaded class has a reference to the manager, and when a forced stop is done it calls a method on the manager which effectively is a timer. If by the time the timer has gone off the threaded class hasn't set a state flag to STOPPED then the manager calls abort on it.

The key thing for me was not just the calling 'stop' but the confirmation that 'stop' had occurred, and understanding that it will be a non-deterministic amount of time but that 'after a reasonable amount of time' that I should give up and move on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .NET [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) class, this way you don't have to handle the stack yourself.

Comment: Not a good answer. There is no Stack (to be managed) here. And it looks like too long a job for the TP.

Comment: @Henk - You *could* replace all this by a call to QueueUserWorkItem. Is this ok in Gergroen context? We can't say, but that maybe worth it.

Comment: pushing it to the TP won't make the looping and stopping(-problem) go away.

Comment: @Henk - Hmm.. I thought he was looking for a nice way to stop a thread. I didn't catch the "forced" term. I suppose I saw the terms "Proper way" and could not imagine they were aside "forced"... And I definitely don't understand how Abort is the right answer to "Proper way".