# What is the least graceful way to stop a .NET thread?

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling

I am in the process of testing some error handling code and am trying to make sure that my application and data always fail into a consistent state.  I have verified the code works with the 'normal' ways of injecting errors, but I want to go a step further.

What is the most abrupt way of killing a .NET thread giving the least chance for error handling to do its thing?

Think for example, how would you test the limit of CLR Constrained Execution Regions?  Or how would I simulate something as serious as pulling the plug?

Comment: nuke it from orbit.

Comment: Unplug the computer.

Comment: @John Rasch As practical as throwing exceptions is, I must admit that few scenarios are as dramatic as an immediate power failure.

Comment: Kill the process from the task manager.

Comment: Maybe you could simulate a power failure by running in a Virtual machine and shutting it down abruptly...

Comment: Look to my question:
[Proper way to stop a threaded job][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146186/proper-way-to-stop-a-threaded-job-forced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could p/invoke the `TerminateThread` windows API function. But that has good chances of corrupting unmanaged state in your program including the state of the CLR itself. So after doing this your process is in an undefined state and it's probably a good idea to kill the whole process.

Answer (score 6):

Cause a Stack Overflow exception - impossible to catch. Just write a function that calls itself.

Comment: I like it, that is pretty serious.  Any idea how to inject it into another thread?

Comment: How you mean, *inject*? A thread starts by calling a delegate, and the code proceeds from there. You'd need to write the thread so it calls something infinitely recursive at some point.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a handle to the thread you can call Thread.Abort();
This throws a ThreadAbortedException on the called thread.

Comment: I already got that far, but what if the system is out of memory and it can't instantiate the ThreadAbortedException?  How would I simulate something of that level?

Comment: This will execute `finally` clauses so it's not really abrupt. And might not even terminate the thread at all.

Comment: If you are out of memory you are going to crash very soon anyway.. :)  Nothing much you can do after that

Comment: @JasonRShaver - If the exception can't be instantiated due to lack of memory then I would guess that a lot of other parts of the program would also be failing due to lack of memory.  So if you are already testing for lack of memory in general, then I would posit that a simple Thread.Abort() under normal conditions would suffice.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - very good point. Even if you don't deliberately write a catch for `ThreadAbortedException`, you might write a `finally` block that throws another exception, which you then do catch!

Comment: @Daniel I'm not sure you can do that. Have you tried that? In general the `ThreadAbortedException` rethrown after a catch block, not sure if it is rethrown after a finally block replacing whatever exception you threw in finally. But the finally block might simply go into an endless loop.

Comment: An exception thrown in a `finally` block replaces the previous exception (if any). Strange examples here: http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/exceptions-part-4-what-happens-if-finally-blocks-always-execute/

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean! `Thread.Abort` doesn't just throw an exception, it also sets an internal thread-local flag, which is checked at the end of *every* catch block, so as to rethrow the `ThreadAbortedException`. So to stop the thread shutting down, you'd need to call `Thread.ResetAbort` which switches off the flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Thread.Abort. This will forcefully throw a ThreadAbortedException on the thread.

The most forceful way, short of cutting power  is of course to kill the process from task manager.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this that doesn't terminate the entire process *and* prevents catch and finally blocks from executing is by pinvoking TerminateThread().  That's a problematic function, usable only in testing scenarios.  It leaks the memory allocated for the stack.  You also have a hard time getting the thread handle you'll need.  That requires pinvoking GetCurrentThread(), that must be done from inside the thread itself.

The state of your test program is random after this, much like it would be when you use Thread.Abort().  Well, worse.

Answer (score 0):

The Thread.Abort is considered evil. One of the possible ways is to have a volatile boolean  which is visible to both the worker and the invoker (Source: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation)

Comment: I think he wants something evil in order to test how his program deals with it.

Comment: I will also add the note that Thread.Abort can cause memory links in C#, exactly the kind of things I am interested in testing.