# How to start a stopped thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading

I create a new thread and start it from a main thread.

```
m_MyThread = new Thread(HandleMyThread);
m_MyThread.IsBackground = true;
m_MyThread.Start();

private void HandleMyThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return;
    }
}
```

After 5 seconds, this thread will finish and its ThreadState is Stopped. I want to start it again when user clicks on button but I get a `ThreadStateException (Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart)`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    m_MyThread.Start(); // ->raise exception
}
```

Please help me how to restart a stopped thread. Thanks.

Comment: For additional information to stop a thread look to my question:
[Proper way to stop a threaded job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146186/proper-way-to-stop-a-threaded-job-forced)

Comment: @Leovo take a look in this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/pausing-and-resuming-threads#interrupting-threads
isn't  an answer, but can helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reuse the thread without new a thread every time , you can consider the implementation of thread pool.

Comment: But in 2 ways, what is the best way because I want to reuse the thread. Please tell me advantages and disadvantages in 2 ways.

Answer (score 16):

I know this question is a bit old, but I thought I would post a response in case others come here.

For this example code, if it were changed to look like this:

```
Thread m_MyThread;
private void HandleMyThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return;
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!m_MyThread.IsAlive)
    {
        m_MyThread = new Thread(HandleMyThread);
        m_MyThread.IsBackground = true;
        m_MyThread.Start();
    }
}
```

This would create a new instance of the thread and start it.  The `ThreadStateException` error is because, simply, you can't re-start a thread that's in a stopped state.  `m_MyThread.Start()` is only valid for threads in the `Unstarted` state.  What needs done in cases like this is to create a new thread instance and invoke `Start()` on the new instance.

Comment: I know that answer is a bit old, but it still fixed my Problem too

Answer (score 3):

Use a `ManualResetEvent`, and instead of `Thread.Sleep`, wait for the event with a timeout.

Then, any other thread can activate the event, and immediately resume the sleeping thread.

Once a thread is exited, it can no longer run.  So don't let it exit.  Instead, put it back to sleep waiting for an event.

Comment: I have a problem in my application. When I run my application, I need to create a thread which sleeps to next 8h AM to raise a event. Please give me the way to solve. At moment, I create a thread and calculate total miliseconds from now to 8h AM so that it will sleep in duration of this time. After finish sleeping, It will raise a event. Do you have any ideals about my way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a new thread like you did when you initially created the thread. You might also want to pull that out into a method to avoid repeating yourself.